# jsonEditor won't bind correctly to jSON object

Tags: asp.net, json

Consider following object:

```
 public class Restrictions
    {
        public Restrictions()
        {
            RestrictedTo = new List<RateRestrictionMembershipModel>();
        }
        public RateRestrictionType RateRestrictionType { get;set;}

        public bool HasRestriction => RestrictedTo.Any();
        public bool IsExclusive { get; set; }
        public List<RateRestrictionMembershipModel> RestrictedTo { get; set; }
    }


    public class RateRestrictionMembershipModel
    {
        public RateRestrictionMembershipModel()
        {

        }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string MembershipId { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Accessing it via `jsonEditor` does not work as expected.
For some reason the deepest object *RateRestrictionMembershipModel* containing 2 string props are not beeing recognized as object members:

[image]

Comment: Is this JavaScript or Java?

Comment: It is c# code serialized

Comment: Does this question actually use JavaScript? Even if not, you might want to add the C# tag.

Comment: updated tag list